# Why does rtabmap have the option to not use an Odom frame

Tags: navigation, odometry, ros-melodic, rtabmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I noticed that rtabmap has the option to use an Odom topic instead of a TF. Why is that?  Is the Odom frame optional against the standard of REP 105

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/350444/why-does-rtabmap-have-the-option-to-not-use-an-odom-frame/) by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 195 on 2020-04-23

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pring](https://answers.ros.org/users/41927/pring/) on 2020-04-25**:
Not exactly sure what use case you're working on, but if your robot has encoders and is publishing on an odom topic, rtabmap can use that to better localize itself. If your robot doesn't publish to /odom, or you don't have a robot at all, rtabmap it relies on keypoint detection for its dead reckonin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Copied answer from https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/issues/535:

rtabmap publishes both TF and the nav_msgs/Odometry topic like this [ROS tutorial](http://library.isr.ist.utl.pt/docs/roswiki/navigation(2f)Tutorials(2f)RobotSetup(2f)Odom.html).

The advantage to use the topic is to get the covariance of the pose. You can also get the twist directly. The disadvantage is when you need to synchronize with other sensors, you may not get the correct transform if the odometry topic cannot be exactly synchronized with the other sensors.

When using odom from TF, you can invert the advantages and disadvantages of the topic above. If you don't care about the covariance, use TF to get accurate transforms for a sensor's timestamp.

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2020-04-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mugetsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/1134/mugetsu/) on 2020-04-27**:
i see, that makes a lot sense thanks!